# How to pass value from another screen to the initial text of a TextField?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `TextField` that needs to have starting text which can be edited and then passed back or saved to device as required.

I used a `TextEditingController()` for the starting text and am struggling with accessing this value from within State of `StatefulWidget`.

Below is my code:

```
class TextFieldScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final initialText;
  const TextFieldScreen({Key key, this.initialText}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TextFieldScreenState createState() => _TextFieldScreenState();
}

class _TextFieldScreenState extends State<TextFieldScreen> {

  final _controller = TextEditingController(text: widget.initialText);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
          child: TextField(
            controller: _controller,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.deepPurple),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))
              ),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

In above code at the line `final _controller = TextEditingController(text: widget.initialText);` I get the error that `only static members can be accessed in initializers`.

So after some searching I understood why this happens and such things need to be initialized in `initState()`, so I added the below code:

```
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        final _controller = TextEditingController(text: widget.initialText);
      }
```

Now the error from before is gone but now my `TextField()` cant access the `conroller:` and I am getting `undefined` error on it.

Is this the correct way to go about this?

And how to I make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can declare `_controller` outside `initState` 
code snippet

```
  TextEditingController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TextEditingController(text: widget.initialText);
  }
```

working demo

[image]
full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextFieldScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final initialText;
  const TextFieldScreen({Key key, this.initialText}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TextFieldScreenState createState() => _TextFieldScreenState();
}

class _TextFieldScreenState extends State<TextFieldScreen> {
  TextEditingController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TextEditingController(text: widget.initialText);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
          child: TextField(
            controller: _controller,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.deepPurple),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFieldScreen(initialText: "abc",),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```